# Generate join table records if non yet created before view presentation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The Product model needs to update its data via a nested form with various data for its join table

```
Product
  has_many :productunits, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :units, through: :productunits
Unit
  has_many :productunits, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :products, through: :productunits
```

When invoking `@productunits = Productunit.where(['product_id = ?', params[:id]]).all` only existing productunits are shown.  If a unit is created in the meantime, the proposed list is incomplete.
The edit action however needs to create new productunits and stufed whith various initial data, if they do not yet exist, **before** presenting them in the view.

What ruby syntax would achieve this result?

**Update**
I've enabled the controller to do the following

```
before_filter :set_product_units, :only => [:edit]
private
def set_product_tipounits
  @units = unit.where(['org_id = ?', session[:org_id]]).all
  @productunits = Productunit.order("id ASC").where(['product_id = ?', params[:id]]).all
  @units.each do |unit|
    @join_created = Productunit.where(['product_id = ? AND unit_id = ?', params[:id], unit.id]).first
    if @join_created.nil?
      @productunit = Productunit.new(:product_id => params[:id], :unit_id => unit.id, :auto_generate => false, :auto_price => false, :release_days => "30")
      @productunit.save      
    end
  end
```

Issue solved...

Comment: To clarify what you're asking, do you mean that you're trying to let a user create a new `productunit`  and then see it in the same form to assign attributes to it before saving it to the database?

Comment: No.  Since Products and Units exist, the join table should have records for each instance of Product for all Units.  I am attempting to create the (eventual) missing ones with initial values, and then presenting the lot to the user.

Comment: Are you trying to do this within the same controller acton that you're calling your `@productunits` definition for?

Comment: Yes, that is the goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad you found a solution, but your solution does insist that your controller know more than it should need to know about the "has_many_through" relationship.

A more abstract solution might be...

In the create method for UnitController

```
def create
...
if @unit.save
  Product.all.each{|p| p.units << @unit unless p.units.include? @unit}
  ...
  end
end
```

Similarly in the ProductController

```
def create
...
if @product.save
  Unit.all.each{|u| u.products << @product unless u.products.include? @product }
  ...
  end
end
```

EDIT
You could also do this as a callback in the model.

```
class Unit << ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :add_to_products

  def add_to_products
    Product.all.each{|p| p.units << self unless p.units.include? self}
  end 
end
```

Comment: Yes, I had a passing thought that this might be a way, where both sides invke the join creation upon their creation. Good to have it spelled out!

Comment: Charm.  Prefer the first alternative for conciseness.

Comment: But second option is more practical if the application is already populated.